# Comparing the efficiency between insertion sort and selection sort

Tags: java, sorting, memory, insertion-sort, selection-sort

So, I have to compare the efficiency of Selection Sort and Insertion Sort. Most of the searches I have done for this give me answers related to the time it takes. My question deals with the memory complexities between the two. Specifically which uses more memory. I don't have a problem with the code. I just don't understand the results.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ShresthaHW2Q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList <Integer> numbersTenInsertion = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputOne = new Scanner(new File("numbers10.txt"));
    while (inputOne.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersTenInsertion.add(new Integer(inputOne.nextInt()));
    }
    ArrayList <Integer> numbersTenSelection = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputTwo = new Scanner(new File("numbers10.txt"));
    while (inputTwo.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersTenSelection.add(new Integer(inputTwo.nextInt()));
    }

    ArrayList <Integer> numbersThirtyInsertion = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputThree = new Scanner(new File("numbers30.txt"));
    while (inputThree.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersThirtyInsertion.add(new Integer(inputThree.nextInt()));
    }
    ArrayList <Integer> numbersThirtySelection = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputFour = new Scanner(new File("numbers30.txt"));
    while (inputFour.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersThirtySelection.add(new Integer(inputFour.nextInt()));
    }

    ArrayList <Integer> numbersFiftyInsertion = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputFive = new Scanner(new File("numbers50.txt"));
    while (inputFive.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersFiftyInsertion.add(new Integer(inputFive.nextInt()));
    }
    ArrayList <Integer> numbersFiftySelection = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    Scanner inputSix = new Scanner(new File("numbers50.txt"));
    while (inputSix.hasNextInt())
    {
        numbersFiftySelection.add(new Integer(inputSix.nextInt()));
    }

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    System.gc();
    long totalMemory = rt.totalMemory();

    long currentMemoryOne;
    selectionSortTen(numbersTenSelection);
    currentMemoryOne = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemoryOne));
    System.gc();

    long currentMemoryTwo;
    insertionSortTen(numbersTenInsertion);
    currentMemoryTwo = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemoryTwo));
    System.gc();

    long currentMemoryThree;
    selectionSortThirty(numbersThirtySelection);
    currentMemoryThree = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemoryThree));
    System.gc();

    long currentMemoryFour;
    insertionSortThirty(numbersThirtyInsertion);
    currentMemoryFour = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemoryFour));
    System.gc();

    long currentMemoryFive;
    selectionSortFifty(numbersFiftySelection);
    currentMemoryFive = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemoryFive));
    System.gc();

    long currentMemorySix;
    insertionSortFifty(numbersFiftyInsertion);
    currentMemorySix = rt.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory used = " + (totalMemory - currentMemorySix));
    System.gc();

}

private static void insertionSortTen (ArrayList<Integer> numbersTenInsertion)

{
    int valueToSort; // holds the value being sorted at each iteration 
    int index; // the index

    for( int k=1; k<numbersTenInsertion.size(); k++ )
    {
        valueToSort = numbersTenInsertion.get(k); // create copy of value being inserted
        // prevents value from being lost 
        index = k;

        while( index > 0 && numbersTenInsertion.get(index-1) > valueToSort )
        {
            numbersTenInsertion.set( index, numbersTenInsertion.get(index-1) );
            index--;
        }
        numbersTenInsertion.set(index, valueToSort );
    }
    //System.out.println(numbersTenInsertion);
}

private static void selectionSortTen (ArrayList<Integer> numbersTenSelection){
    int max, i ,j;
    int valueToSortTwo;
    for (i = 0; i < numbersTenSelection.size()-1; i++)
     {
       max = i;
       for (j = i+1; j < numbersTenSelection.size(); j++)
       {
         if (numbersTenSelection.get(max).compareTo(numbersTenSelection.get(j)) > 0)
           max = j;
       }
       valueToSortTwo = numbersTenSelection.get(i);
       numbersTenSelection.set(i, numbersTenSelection.get(max));
       numbersTenSelection.set(max, valueToSortTwo);
     }
    //System.out.println(numbersTenSelection);
}

private static void insertionSortThirty (ArrayList<Integer> numbersThirtyInsertion)

{
    int valueToSort; // holds the value being sorted at each iteration 
    int index; // the index

    for( int k=1; k<numbersThirtyInsertion.size(); k++ )
    {
        valueToSort = numbersThirtyInsertion.get(k); // create copy of value being inserted
        // prevents value from being lost 
        index = k;

        while( index > 0 && numbersThirtyInsertion.get(index-1) > valueToSort )
        {
            numbersThirtyInsertion.set( index, numbersThirtyInsertion.get(index-1) );
            index--;
        }
        numbersThirtyInsertion.set(index, valueToSort );
    }
    //System.out.println(numbersThirtyInsertion);
}

private static void selectionSortThirty (ArrayList<Integer> numbersThirtySelection){
    int max, i ,j;
    int valueToSortTwo;
    for (i = 0; i < numbersThirtySelection.size()-1; i++)
     {
       max = i;
       for (j = i+1; j < numbersThirtySelection.size(); j++)
       {
         if (numbersThirtySelection.get(max).compareTo(numbersThirtySelection.get(j)) > 0)
           max = j;
       }
       valueToSortTwo = numbersThirtySelection.get(i);
       numbersThirtySelection.set(i, numbersThirtySelection.get(max));
       numbersThirtySelection.set(max, valueToSortTwo);
     }
    //System.out.println(numbersThirtySelection);
}

private static void insertionSortFifty (ArrayList<Integer> numbersFiftyInsertion)

{
    int valueToSort; // holds the value being sorted at each iteration 
    int index; // the index

    for( int k=1; k<numbersFiftyInsertion.size(); k++ )
    {
        valueToSort = numbersFiftyInsertion.get(k); // create copy of value being inserted
        // prevents value from being lost 
        index = k;

        while( index > 0 && numbersFiftyInsertion.get(index-1) > valueToSort )
        {
            numbersFiftyInsertion.set( index, numbersFiftyInsertion.get(index-1) );
            index--;
        }
        numbersFiftyInsertion.set(index, valueToSort );
    }
    //System.out.println(numbersFiftyInsertion);
}

private static void selectionSortFifty (ArrayList<Integer> numbersFiftySelection){
    int max, i ,j;
    int valueToSortTwo;
    for (i = 0; i < numbersFiftySelection.size()-1; i++)
     {
       max = i;
       for (j = i+1; j < numbersFiftySelection.size(); j++)
       {
         if (numbersFiftySelection.get(max).compareTo(numbersFiftySelection.get(j)) > 0)
           max = j;
       }
       valueToSortTwo = numbersFiftySelection.get(i);
       numbersFiftySelection.set(i, numbersFiftySelection.get(max));
       numbersFiftySelection.set(max, valueToSortTwo);
     }
    //System.out.println(numbersFiftySelection);
}

}
```

The results I get are:

```
Memory used = 4906504 (selection sort of arraylist with 10000 integers)
Memory used = 4697664 (insertion sort of arraylist with 10000 integers)

Memory used = 4849512 (selection sort of arraylist with 30000 integers)
Memory used = 3693496 (insertion sort of arraylist with 30000 integers)

Memory used = 3360632 (selection sort of arraylist with 50000 integers)
Memory used = 2276056 (insertion sort of arraylist with 50000 integers)
```

I don't understand how, given that the `ArrayList` has more integers, why is the memory used decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to measure the memory used by a particular algorithm in Java because of garbage collection. If you call a method and measure the space available before and after, you may end up getting wildly different numbers if the JVM started garbage collecting in the middle of the method versus waiting until after the method finishes to do a garbage collection. As a result, this approach to measuring memory is probably not ideal.

A more direct way to do this would be to just look at the code and see how much memory ends up being used. A properly-implemented version of insertion sort should only require O(1) auxiliary memory, and a proper version of selection sort should also only require O(1) auxiliary memory - there's no recursion involved, no auxiliary arrays required, and the only information you need are a couple of indices.